# Database design - connect each company with all possible post codes to store distance

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am trying to design a database that has a table containing all companies offering the service of interest and then I need a way to store for each company the distance to each possible post code (~10.000).
The idea is each company operates in a specific distance that can change from time to time.

I have 3 ideas but none really feels right:

1. Have a table that has a row for each post code and a column for each company (60 * 10.000) and stores the distance as a value. Problem I would need to use the company id as column name and don't know if that is the correct way.
2. Have for each company a new table that has a column post code and distance (2 * 10.000). Problem the company id would be the table name, again not sure if that is the correct way.
3. A table with 3 columns CompanyID, Post code, Distance (3 * 600.000). That feels most correct but would mean a lot of rows.

Can anyone tell me if there is a better way or which alternative to pick?

Comment: *"then I need a way to store for each company the distance to each possible post code (~10.000)"* - why? Why not store their location and delivery radius?

Comment: I'd go with option 4

Comment: I do store their delivery radius, but if I don'T calculate all distances I have to recalculate them each time I want to know which company offers services for that post code. That feels not really intuitive, since the distance from the company to the post code will rarely change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing the last option. You shouldn't be worried about having too many rows as long as you have indexes set. Here is an example implementation (MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE `company`
(
    `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `post_code`
(
    `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `postal_code` VARCHAR(10),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `distance`
(

    `comnpany_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `post_code_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `distance` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`,`post_code_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `distance_FK_1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`)
        REFERENCES `company` (`id`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `distance_FK_2`
        FOREIGN KEY (`post_code_id`)
        REFERENCES `post_code` (`id`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Thanks! Does creating a table just to store the post code bring any benefit over using the post code directly in the distance table?

Comment: Depends on the length and format of the postal code. In case it is more than 4 chars (4 bytes) you'll save space/memory if postal codes are stored in a dedicated table.

Comment: It is 5 chars. Thanks!

Comment: If it is a 5 digit code (like the one in USA), you can store it in decimal(5) field. You just need to trim the leading zeros (01234 will be stored as 1234 in the database).